# Google Cloud Storage static IP address

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to obtain a static IP address for a Google Cloud Storage bucket for use with DNS? I wish to host it at mydomain.com, and because I also have e-mail at mydomain.com, I cannot use a DNS CNAME record -- I need to use an IP address and an DNS A record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but doing so requires using Google Cloud Load Balancer: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing. The upside of this approach is that it comes with a number of useful features, like mapping a collection of buckets and compute resources to a single domain, as well as the static IP address you want. The downside is that there's additional cost and complexity.

I recommend just using a subdomain and a CNAME record, if you don't need any of the other features.

Comment: Hey I am facing the same problem. How do we create a subdomain tho? is it same like creating another bucket with subdomain.domain.com ?

Comment: Yes, just so. And then add a CNAME to your DNS record mapping subdomain.domain.com to `c.storage.googleapis.com.`

Comment: CNAME-way offers HTTP-only access to your resources, read the [Caution](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)

Comment: So if I need only static IP to my bucket, cname record is good enough?

Comment: Yes, so long as you don't need to use HTTPS.

Answer (score -2):

Check it with google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses).
You can manage it on instance page in networking section.

Comment: Thanks -- I saw that, but it appears specific to VM instances, and I'm strictly using cloud storage with no VM instances. I didn't see where it was possible to use this with cloud storage specifically, unless you see something?