# Is there any way to use particular hosts of storage.googleapis.com?

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-storage, ip, client, hosts

I actually have a requirement where I want to create the storage client using particular hosts from storage.googleapis.com. When we fetch hosts from storage.googleapis.com we get around 10-12 different remote Ips. I want to create client or call the client methods on particular set of hosts like out of 10-12 I want to have 5-6 hosts on which I would like to create client.

```
ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex("storage.googleapis.com")
>> ['172.253.62.128', '172.253.115.128', '172.253.122.128', '17......]
```

Out of the above array I want to use particular Ip to make a storage client. For an example on `172.253.62.128`.
I am not sure if this is possible. What I am trying to do is if in anycase a Ip is blacklisted on our end we want to create a storage client on new host and want to avoid the last blacklisted Ip.

There is an option to pass an `endpoint` while creating storage client. But it doesn't look helpful as i get bucket not found error.

Note: I am using ruby application.
Look at the following ruby documentation:
https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-storage/latest/Google/Cloud/Storage.html#new-class_method

Comment: I understand that you want to restrict the set of ip's from where Google Cloud Storage API is serving you, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Is it necessary to be from a specific IP address? Is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45089972/13171940) similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: If you are using HTTPS to talk to Cloud Storage, you cannot specify hostnames as IP addresses. That will cause an SSL certificate validation error. In other words, you cannot specify IP-based endpoints.

Comment: So the thing is I am creating Cloud Storage client on one of the server. The server is selected at random which connects to the google cloud and does the things. The problem is that the storage client may have picked a Ip which may be blacklisted by us or is getting filtered due to some reason. In such cases I want to create new storage client using new Ip.

Comment: 1) Why are you blacklisting Google Cloud Storage servers? That makes no sense. 2) Google servers can redirect clients to an available service endpoint. Even if you could set the hostname to an IP address, your strategy of selecting the host will break if Google redirects you to a server on your blacklist.

Comment: So we are not blacklisting, the thing is we have a logic which checks for DDoS attacks so what happens our logic blacklists it. I was thinking of one approach that what if I explicitly create an entry for host/etc file with ip to domain name entries. It will make only calls on those servers only. is that correct?

Comment: 1) No, that is not correct. If the GCP libraries receive a redirect, it will follow the redirect to the new endpoint. 2) You cannot prevent a Google Cloud Storage DDoS because that will never happen. Why do you think it could happen?

Comment: Eh I get that that GCS can redirect to different host, and I am fine with it as because that is something GCS is doing on their end from their host so I don't think that will cause any problem. My major problem is that I can't change the logic to avoid blacklisting of Ip as we don't have access to that filtering logic. So my approach was to pick the first host only which is valid and then rest the request can propagate as it want to.